# removing dependencies as duplicate in child pom.xml introduces errors as dependencies are in parent pom.xml

Tags: java, xml, maven, intellij-idea

There was new maven module introduced in IntelliJ.

newPom.xml has dependencies that are part of the Parent POM being referenced.

During development, we used the intelliJ features to add the dependencies to resolve issues.

During code review, we were asked to remove the dependencies as they are supposed to be present in parent POM.XML

We removed the dependencies as dependencies present in the parent POM.XML file.

Errors started to appear for all the classes we introduced as part of the Child POM.XML, after the redundant dependencies were cleared per the code review comments.

My question is what needs to be done to resolve these errors, as the dependencies are part of the parent POM.XML

Any guidance, while I am doing my research on the same at the earliest.

Comment: Please post some code, examples, etc.

Comment: Please delete your intellij project completely, and reimport the project from the parten pom, modules and all, overwriting any intellij files if necessary.

Comment: First, make sure the Maven configuration is correct: `mvn compile` for the module must complete successfully. Then make sure you have the parent pom.xml file also imported into IDE project (you can import it from Maven projects tool window). Or you can import the Maven project (from parent pom.xml) as @Engineer Dollery suggested.

Comment: @Andrey my question is because of the issues that come up while the dependencies are removed, as it is needless to say mvn compile will NOT complete successfully. Parent POM.XML is always imported, but when we tried to get the parent pom, we were not able to obtain the same, making us think about the first point mentioned by you, if the Maven configuration is correct. "Not sure when you mentioned you can import it from Maven projects tool window, how it can be done"

Answer (score 1):

If the dependencies are in the parent pom, they are inherited by the child project. So somewhere, there is a mistake.

First of all, check with `mvn dependency:list` on the child project that the dependencies are really missing. Then check whether the correct version of the parent pom is referenced.

One common area of confusion is if the parent pom declares `<dependencyManagement>`. The entries in here are not dependencies, even if they look like dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.
mvn dependency:list has not downloaded the parent pom module dependencies, we just checked

Comment: parent pom declares <dependencyManagement>

Comment: @Ajay Are the "lost" dependencies declared outside the dependencyManagement or inside? Dependencies declared in dependencyManagement are not real dependencies and need to be declared again as dependencies (in the parent or child).

Comment: the lost dependencies are not declared outside the dependencyManagement

Comment: Then the removal of the dependencies was wrong and should be reversed. Your code reviewer apparently made a mistake.

Comment: That is exactly what has happened!! Thanks JF Meier. It is still to be resolved!!!

Comment: Shouldn't the classes introduced as part of the child module, shall not show errors as the required jar files are declared as dependencies in the parent module POM.XML?? @JF Meier ? thoughts ??

Comment: If they are in the dependencyManagement section, they are _not_ declared as dependencies. Entries of dependencyManagement are purely for overriding versions and scope.

Comment: Yes, I am clear. Thanks a lot @JF Meier. Appreciate time and patience!!! :)

Comment: on the same note, one more question >>> 
Was discussing with my Colleague, if that were to be the case Spring boot projects download all the dependencies without we mentioning their dependency, this is exactly what is being expected in this situation...

Comment: Spring boot does some magic. I do not know how it gathers the dependencies.